# clearInterval on hover and setInterval onmouseout

Tags: jquery, hover, carousel, setinterval, clearinterval

I have created a carousel that slides every 5 seconds automatically (as well as having manual buttons to move slides). I want to be able to pause the scrolling when the mouse is hovered over a slide, and resume when the mouse is no longer hovered.

So far my script will do all of the above.
However it won't start on page load, you have to hover over and then un-hover for it to start.

Here is my script:

```
jQuery('#viewport').hover(function () {
    window.clearInterval(timer);
}, function () {
    timer = window.setInterval(function () {
        jQuery('#next').trigger('click');
    }, 1000);
});
```

What can I do to get this to start sliding straight away?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jQuery('#viewport').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        clearInterval( $(this).data('timer') );
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).data('timer', setInterval(function () {
            jQuery('#next').trigger('click');
        }, 1000));
    }
}).trigger('mouseleave');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function nextSlide () {
   jQuery('#next').trigger('click');
} 

jQuery('#viewport').hover(function() {
  window.clearInterval(timer);    
}, function() {
  timer = window.setInterval(nextSlide, 1000);
});

nextSlide();
```

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work, same issue of not starting off with the autoslide

Comment: What thing didnt work ? Can you reproduce the same on jsfiddle ?

Answer (score -3):

Wrap everything inside

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Your code there.
});
```

Comment: That does not solve the issue of starting the slide show on page load.  That simply wraps the ode to ensure it is executed after the DOM is loaded but you are still missing something to trigger the actual slide show.